# Maven indirect dependencies

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a java ee maven project. The project has some dependencies in pom. But also it has some indirect dependencies (dependencies of dependencies). While deploying the app I have some ClasNotFound exceptions of classes in this indirect dependencies. How can I resolve them except adding them in Glassfish CLASSPATH?

Comment: Give us a concrete example, with a real pom, and a real list of jar files put in the app's classpath.

Comment: Transitive dependencies are by default included. It can be a problem of your deployment tool (m2e in Eclispe for example has similar issues).